# WCF Deserialize JSON String

Tags: c#, wcf

I had edited my question :

How can i deserialize the JSON string shows below :

```
"{\"acctId\": \"Test10001\",\"amount\": 200,\"currency\": \"USD\",\"Code\": \"Test\",\"serialNo\": \"1234566789asdsad0\"}"
```

Please give suggestion how can I get the data by using this method or any other recommended method.

Comment: expose your full function

Comment: `res` is JSON string. So use of `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(res);` is wrong here. Deserialize `res` using JSON serializer like `JSON.NET`

Comment: if that other way of deserialize without using other library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code should serve your purpose:

```
    public class DeserializedData
    {
        public string acctId { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string serialNo { get; set; }
    }    

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);
string res = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Use third party dlls like Json.NET or Restsharp:

1.) Using Json.Net [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedData>(res);
```

2.) Using Restsharp  [Restsharp](http://restsharp.org/)

```
var jsonDeserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
var response = jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<DeserializedData>(res);
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, thats work. You save my time , thanks again =)

Comment: No worries, mate!!

Comment: @saket is your bug fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting you to use `StreamWriter` as below. 
Use this function and pass your string and return a the Stream which will give you the desired JSON Content

```
public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
         MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
         StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
         writer.Write(s);
         writer.Flush();
         stream.Position = 0;
         return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The payload of your POST request seems to be in JSON format, so you should use a JSON parsing library to parse it, such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Then you would write something like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourRequestObject>(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read Json string like this

```
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(res.ToString());

        string acctId= stuff.acctId;
```

But the response string you are parsing should be json formatted.